# ASP.NET Core how to redirect user to a page depending on a boolean

Tags: asp.net-core

To keep it short i have a razor pages / mvc project where user must have be locked to a specific page based on a boolean value in database.

If this value is true the user cannot access any other page and if tries to access them he is redirected to his lockdown page which can only be unlocked after he enters some credentials on a form. It's not a login page because user must be authenticated to access it.

I would like to know what's the best way to achieve this generally on the whole application so i don't need to do the check on every page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resource filter sounds like a good fit. Something along the lines of:

```
public class BoolResourceFilter : IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private readonly MyContext _db;
    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory _urlHelperFactory;

    public BoolResourceFilter(MyContext db, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory)
    {
        _db = db;
        _urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
    }

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var boolValue = await _db...; // get your bool value;
        var urlHelper = _urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(context);
        var redirectUrl = urlHelper.Page("~/TruePage");
        var currentUrl = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;

        // In addition to checking the boolValue, you need to check that
        // the URL of the request is not to the redirect page already
        // to prevent infinite redirect loop
        if (boolValue && currentUrl != redirectUrl)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectResult(redirectUrl);
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Then, in `Startup.ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddScoped<BoolResourceFilter>();

...

services.AddMvc(o =>
{
    o.Filters.Add(typeof(BoolResourceFilter));
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);;
```

Comment: I haven't used filters before specially a resource one, how do i use this? do i have to use it on page as attribute or something?

Comment: I think your comment came from before I updated my answer. If that's not what you were looking for, please expand.

Comment: According to the docs: "Resource filters are useful to short-circuit most of the pipeline. For example, a caching filter can avoid the rest of the pipeline on a cache hit." Essentially, it gives you a hook into the request pipeline, and specifically for resource filter, a hook before much happens, providing an opportunity to short circuit the pipeline, such as by returning a redirect.

Comment: so if a user is logged on my application and he is trying to redirect to somewhere, this resource filter will trigger and redirect him to the lockdown page if on database the boolean is true? that sounds pretty nice, i have to look deeper into it

Comment: In `ConfigureServices`, I added it as a global filter, which means that it will run on every request, before any action/page is actually invoked (because it's a resource filter). It's going to then get the value from the database, and if it's true, then it's going to redirect the user to that redirect page. It also checks that the requested URL isn't actually the redirect page, or it will also catch the request for that page that the client will make after the redirect and attempt redirect again (endless loop).

Comment: Wish i knew about this before, i did something similar with policies but i had to use multiple on them on each page. I will try implement this instead cause this is exactly what i needed

Comment: There's other types of filters, and if you're doing something policy based an authorization filter might be a better fit. Basically, each filter type fits into a different place in the request pipeline, and you want to use the one that's closest to the functionality you're trying to enhance. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2.